# Bash if statement with logical OR

Tags: if-statement, logical-operators

I want the commands to execute only when the string variables are **not equal** to foo **or** any word starting with bar.

```
if [[ $string != "foo" || $string != bar* ]]; then
commands
fi
```

When $string=foo and I use the following code it works fine and no commands execute:

```
if [[ $string != "foo" ]]; then
commands
fi
```

but when I add the second part with the || the commands execute when they should not.

Comment: You need && instead of ||. Think about it.

Answer (score 7):

You need an *and*, not an *or*:

```
 if [[ $string != "foo" && $string != bar* ]] ...
```

What your code is saying is that "it must be true that either the string is not equal to foo, or the string does not start with bar" - that's true for all strings.

What you need to say is "it must be true that the string is not equal too foo, **and** the string does not start with bar".

(You might want to put double-quotes around `$string` as well, if there's a chance it could be empty.)